Непонятное объявление класса
Не могу нигде найти объяснение этому определению класса с круглыми скобками после имени из "Tutorial: Use dependency injection in .NET":
internal sealed class ServiceLifetimeReporter(
    IExampleTransientService transientService,
    IExampleScopedService scopedService,
    IExampleSingletonService singletonService)
{
    public void ReportServiceLifetimeDetails(string lifetimeDetails)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(lifetimeDetails);

        LogService(transientService, "Always different");
        LogService(scopedService, "Changes only with lifetime");
        LogService(singletonService, "Always the same");
    }

    private static void LogService<T>(T service, string message)
        where T : IReportServiceLifetime =>
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"    {typeof(T).Name}: {service.Id} ({message})");
}


Это новая фича: primary constructor. 1, 2

@AlexanderPetrov тянет на ответ.
